# Unable to access application properly through Apache HTTPD loadbalancer with mod_jk

Tags: apache, load-balancing, httpd.conf, jboss6.x, mod-jk

I am trying to setup a JBOSS 6.4 EAP cluster having two nodes on a RHEL 7 VM. I have deployed my application on 2 JBOSS instances and configured `mod_jk` in Apache HTTPD server. The `httpd.conf` is as follows:

```
ServerRoot "/usr/local/apache2"
Listen 192.168.xxx.xxx:83
<IfModule !mpm_netware_module>
<IfModule !mpm_winnt_module>
User daemon
Group daemon
</IfModule>
</IfModule>
ServerAdmin you@example.com
DocumentRoot "/usr/local/apache2/htdocs"
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>
<Directory "/usr/local/apache2/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html
</IfModule>
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Satisfy All
</FilesMatch>
ErrorLog "logs/error_log"
LogLevel debug
<IfModule log_config_module>
</IfModule>
<IfModule alias_module>
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/usr/local/apache2/cgi-bin/"
</IfModule>
<IfModule cgid_module>
</IfModule>
<Directory "/usr/local/apache2/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
DefaultType text/plain
<IfModule mime_module>
    TypesConfig conf/mime.types
    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
</IfModule>
<IfModule ssl_module>
SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
</IfModule>
Include /usr/local/apache2/conf/mod-jk.conf
```

The `mod-jk.conf` is as follows:

```
# Load mod_jk module
# Specify the filename of the mod_jk lib
LoadModule jk_module modules/mod_jk.so

# Where to find workers.properties
JkWorkersFile conf/workers.properties

# Where to put jk logs
JkLogFile logs/mod_jk.log

# Set the jk log level [debug/error/info]
JkLogLevel debug

# Select the log format
JkLogStampFormat  "[%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y]"

# JkOptions indicates to send SSK KEY SIZE
JkOptions +ForwardKeySize +ForwardURICompat -ForwardDirectories

# JkRequestLogFormat
JkRequestLogFormat "%w %V %T"

# Mount your applications
# The default setting only sends Java application data to mod_jk.
# Use the commented-out line to send all URLs through mod_jk.
# JkMount /* loadbalancer
JkMount /* loadbalancer
# Add shared memory.
# This directive is present with 1.2.10 and
# later versions of mod_jk, and is needed for
# for load balancing to work properly
JkShmFile logs/jk.shm 

# Add jkstatus for managing runtime data
<Location /jkstatus/>
JkMount status1
Order deny,allow
#Deny from all
#Allow from 127.0.0.1
Allow from 0.0.0.0
</Location>

JkMountFile conf/uriworkermap.properties
```

and `workers.properties` is as follows:

```
# workers to contact, that's what you have in your httpd.conf
worker.list=loadbalancer,status1

#setup node1
worker.node1.port=8009
worker.node1.host=xyz.abc.com
worker.node1.type=ajp13
worker.node1.lbfactor=1

#setup node2
worker.node2.port=8010
worker.node2.host=xyz.abc.com
worker.node2.type=ajp13
worker.node2.lbfactor=1

#setup the load-balancer
worker.loadbalancer.type=lb
worker.loadbalancer.balance_workers=node1,node2
worker.loadbalancer.sticky_session=1

# Status worker for managing load balancer
worker.status1.type=status
```

This configuration works, I am able to access the application from load balancer, but the images on the login page do not show up (`302` Redirect with `Location` pointing to loadbalancer URL is received in the http response.)
The JBOSS instances are running on port `8080` and `8081` while Apache HTTPd  2.4 with mod_jk is running on port `83`.

I have no other module installed in Apache except mod_jk.
My research has led me to find that such problems are faced when application server is configured in SSL. I am not using SSL, I am using only HTTP.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

**Edit 1:**

I figured out that it is an issue with the security module in my application. The requests that mod_jk forwards to the nodes is exactly the same as it received from the client i.e. along with the host name and port number of the Apache HTTPD.

So, if Apache is running on `http://abc.mydomain.com:83/` and request received is `http://abc.mydomain.com:83/myApp`, mod_jk forwards the request (`http://abc.mydomain.com:83/myApp`)to a worker node which is running on, say JBOSS on URL `http://pqr.mydomain.com:8081/myApp`.
 Lets say I have two worker nodes with same application `myApp`.

I figured that the security module in `myApp` compares thehost name and  port number received request URL with its own. This is a requirement which is absolutey necessary. 
So I have to use mod_rewrite for the request URL to be that of the worker node.
My question is: How to I configure the mod_rewite so that the requests are load balanced and rewritten appropriately?

Like, one request with URL  `http://abc.mydomain.com:83/myApp` is forwarded to node1 and rewritten as `http://pqr.mydomain.com:8081/myApp`

while the next is forwarded to node2 and rewritten as `http://uvw.mydomain.com:8091/myApp` ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know mod_jk, but here is a tip. Under httpd, if you were using mod_proxy, that just needs the necessary ProxyPassRereverse directive, specific to catch redirects from the backend without the hostname and scheme the client is using, probably mod_jk has something similar.